# Prove a planar graph with all regions having even degree can be colored with 2 colors

Tags: graph-theory

My current idea is to use the dual graph, and prove that that is a bipartite graph, and so proving the statement. But I can't seem to figure out how even degree for all verticies means that it is bipartite.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloring the regions of the dual graph might be simpler to visualize. In any case we cannot do without geometry, because the statement would not hold, e.g., on a Moebius strip.

All vertices of dual graph have even degree. We have to show that any loop in the "dual world" that avoids the vertices crosses an even number of edges. Draw such a loop and try to retract it to a point. Whenever in this process you draw it over a vertex you add or subtract an even number of crossings. Since at the end you have zero crossings the number of these had to be even at the beginning.

From this it easily follows that we can $2$-color the regions of the dual graph.